# Table rows does not render properly when Locker Service is Enabled

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I have an issue where the Rows and columns appear as plain text instead of rows and columns when Locker service is enabled, but when I disable the Locker service I can see the data as proper rows and columns.

> Lightning component.

```
<aura:component >

  <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer" aura:id="targetTable">
        <thead aura:id="targetDetailsHead" class="targetHead"></thead>
        <tbody aura:id="targetDetailsBody" class="targetBody"></tbody>
            </table>
<ui:button aura:id="button" buttonTitle="Click to see what you put into the table" class="button" label="Generate" press="{!c.myAction}"/>    
</aura:component>
```

> Controller.JS

```
({
    myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
        var tableColList = ['<tr> <th>Colval1</th>' ,'<th>Colval2</th> ','<th>Colval3</th> ','<th>Colval4</th> ' ,'<th>Colval5</th> ','<th>Colval6</th> </tr>'];
        var tableRowList = ['<tr><td>Rowval1</td>' ,'<td>Rowval2</td>','<td>Rowval3</td>','<td>Rowval4</td>' ,'<td>Rowval5</td>','<td>Rowval6</td>'];
         var targetDetailsHead = component.find("targetDetailsHead");
          var targetDetailsBody = component.find("targetDetailsBody");
            var thead= '', tbody= '';
        console.log(tableColList.length);
                for (var i = 0, listLength = tableColList.length; i < listLength; i++) {
                    if (tableColList.length > 0 && tableRowList.length > 0 ) {
                        thead=thead+tableColList[i];
                        tbody=tbody+tableRowList[i];
                    } 
                }
                console.log('---Table Head---',thead);
                console.log('---Table Body---',tbody);
                targetDetailsHead.getElement().innerHTML += thead;
                targetDetailsBody.getElement().innerHTML += tbody;
                console.log('---Table Head with innerHTML---',targetDetailsHead.getElement().innerHTML);
                console.log('---Table Body with innerHTML---',targetDetailsBody.getElement().innerHTML);


    }
})
```

Am I missing something? Any suggestions will help me, Thanks !

Image below indicates Locker Service Enabled : 
[image: Locker Enabled]

Image below indicates Locker Service Disabled
[image: Locker Disabled]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LockerService will run any "raw" HTML text through a library called [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) which will sanitize the HTML for any potential XSS threats. DOMPurify makes a call to `new DOMParser().parseFromString()` passing along the raw HTML before doing it's analysis. Using your example above, when you call `innerHTML`, the underlying call in DOMPurify is:

`new DOMParser().parseFromString("<tr> <th>Colval1</th><th>Colval2</th> <th>Colval3</th> <th>Colval4</th> <th>Colval5</th> <th>Colval6</th> </tr>", 'text/html')`

Which strips the `<tr>` and `<th>` element tags since that is not a valid HTML structure outside of the `<table>` element. If you run the same command with that code wrapped in `<table>` and `<thead>` elements you get the exected DOM back:

`new DOMParser().parseFromString("<table><thead><tr> <th>Colval1</th><th>Colval2</th> <th>Colval3</th> <th>Colval4</th> <th>Colval5</th> <th>Colval6</th> </tr></thead></table>", 'text/html')`

So I suggest only setting innerHTML values to DOM that is valid standalone, or using the `HTMLTableElement` javascript APIs, like [`createTHead()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/createTHead) and [`insertRow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow), to dynamically create your table.

Comment: Hi #TrevorBilss  Thanks alot for response. can you please guide me where should I change my code exactly ??

Comment: Hey thanks  man!  #Trevor It worked like a charm. Now I understand we need to pass the whole valid HTML to make it count !